# Mantis deletion issue

Tags: mantis

460 of 490 reports aren't showing up in View Issues. On the other hand, they're still showing up under Summary and all of the reports look like they're still accessible. Only 30 issues are showing up in View Issues. The reports can also be accessed by typing in the number and clicking Jump.

Also, even though I get 10 pages of results (490 reports) when I click Summary and then 365 under days and I can click the issue number to view the report. But when I click Excel Export, it only exports the 30 issues to the excel file.

Nothing was changed in Manage Configuration, but it's possible a rogue developer deleted all of them. If they were deleted, why are they still showing up under Summary and My Views? In any case, is there some way that I can get all of the reports to start showing up in View Issues again?

Answer (score 1):

I found out you just needed to select "reset filters" since a filter got turned on somehow.